# Trigger job on push on commit which is in a PR via if condition

Tags: github, github-actions

My job doesn't seem to trigger when I force push to a branch which is currently in a PR. Here is my workflow file:

```
name: Test

on:
    pull_request:
        types: [synchronize]

jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        strategy:
            matrix:
                node-version: [12.x]
        steps:
            - name: test
              if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'synchronize'
              run: echo hello
```

The result:

[image]

Does anyone know why it isn't triggering?

Comment: Have you looked at the [events](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/activity#events) that *are* being triggered? Also your title asks about the `if` condition but that seems to be the same as the `on` condition anyway.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm thinking of including the on push also, so would like specific jobs to run only when a commit has been newly pushed the repo to a branch which also happens to be in a PR. I can't for the life of me find any information on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was at the bottom of the PR. It stated there were merge conflicts when trying to rebase onto master.

If there are merge conflicts it will not trigger a pull_request event on the GitHub actions pipeline. I fixed it by resolving the merge conflict.